# media query block display:none issue

Tags: html, css, media

Got small problem with media queries 
inside my html
one of my sections includes this

```
 <div class="header-left">
    </div>
    <div class="header-center">
    <ul>
            <li class="end"><a href="#">ETc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Etc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Etc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Etc</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
    </div>
```

this here is my header section of website I separated it into 3 sections header right and left are just empty place holders to keep center in middle
when I use media queries at lower width I want the left and right to disappear
for that I used

```html
@media(max-width:600px){
 
 .header-left{display:none;}
 .header-right{display:none;}   
 }
```

for css properties for these 3 I use the max-width as well as % to make sure they stay in the position I want them to be in
and it all works fine for every element on left side so in this part
.header-left
however the .header-right does not disappear when its re-sized is there way to fix it or am I just doing it wrong in this example?

Answer (score 0):

Since this fiddle works with your code you provided https://jsfiddle.net/uhqugL7n/

try adding `!important` to  `.header-left` and `.header-left` like this:

`.header-left{display:none !important;}`

It is most likely that something is overriding your media query.

also be sure to have something like this in your head section of your page:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`